# Focus a tab by Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page that have 2 tabs **settings1, settings2**. I want to focus the tabs according to tab_id from javascript. My code is below;

HTML

```
<form action="action_here" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form11">
    <ul class="tab">
        <li><a href="javascript:FormSubmit('1','btn_tab1');" class="tablinks" id="selected_tab1" onclick="openTab(event,'settings1','1');" onfocus="openTab(event,'settings1','1')">settings1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:FormSubmit('2','btn_tab2');" class="tablinks" id="selected_tab2" onclick="openTab(event,'settings2','2')" onfocus="openTab(event,'settings2','2')">settings2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="tab_id1" name="tab_id" >
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var tab_id = document.getElementById("tab_id1").value;
if(tab_id == 1){
    alert("1");
    document.getElementById('selected_tab1').focus();
} else if (tab_id == 2) {
    alert("2");
    document.getElementById('selected_tab2').focus();
}
```

Issues:

1. when page first loaded no tabs are selected. I want to select tab 1 **settings1**.

2.When I select  tab, tab won't selected, but tab_ids are printing right by javascript.

Plaese Help me with this.

Comment: When is your code executed? I think you want to make sure your DOM content is loaded first. _document ready_ is your friend. (Whatever implementation you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure your code gets called after your DOM content is ready. If you don't want to use something like `jQuery` you can do something like this:

```
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

ready(function() {
  // your code
})
```

The implementation of *document ready* was taken from [you might not need jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready).

Comment: @tenten That's weird, because it's working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yhpqxgkk/